# How do I create a H2 database inside a java project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, h2

I want to create an embedded H2 database in my simple java project in Eclipse. How do I do this programatically and package the db inside my code ? I tried a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154636/embedding-the-java-h2-database-programmatically) for this 
and got an error in my code.

Code -

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:˜/test");
    ds.setUser("sa");
    ds.setPassword("sa");
    try {
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Error -

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the 
current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:˜/test". 
Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-181]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.getName(ConnectionInfo.java:398)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:45)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:167)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:145)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:128)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:26)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:347)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:92)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:190)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at MyCode.main(MyCode.java:8)
```

I saw this link - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/h2-database/SlSwte0DLSU/eWj0UaejdkEJ and [Where are my H2 database files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397716/where-are-my-h2-database-files). Its not clear how I can get the exact path to test database on my windows pc.

How do I first access the test database and then create another database inside my java project ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the character before the slash in that URL is a normal tilde and not some other Unicode character that looks similar? I'm pretty sure it's not the same character as in the example given in the error message.

Comment: @IanRoberts - Thanks. I never used tilde and would not have been able to figure it out. Btw, can you also tell me how to create a database inside the java project and maybe even view it ? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I did a simple test to find out if the table is in RAM or harddrive. It seems to be in harddrive. Reason - I ran my code and it created a db with table. Then, I ran the code again and it tells me that the table already exists. Now, how do I find the location of the DB in my harddrive ?

Comment: Your file will look like `jdbc:h2:{path}/{filename}` where the file name will be `{filename}.h2.db` I'd suggest checking your working directory (refresh it). Alternatively check the documents folder whatever that is for the OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have used the wrong character. You need to use `~` (tilde) and you have use `˜` (I don't know what it is, but it's not a tilde).

Answer (score 1):

The location of the H2 files is very [nicely documented](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files). To view the contents, execute the h2.jar. It is not only the driver, but also an executable that will start a web-based applications for DB management.