# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In the code I do not even use entityManagerFactory. I extend JPARepository and for creating the tables I have entities annotated with @Entity (using javax.persistence). But still I am getting these errors **creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'** -> caused by  javax.persistence.PersistenceException -> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException -> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException -> **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException.**

My application.properties contains:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/MetaVerseDB
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>uni.fmi.masters</groupId>
    <artifactId>meta-verse</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>meta-verse</name>
    <description>Our great and friendly web space to share weather data</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have all the required dependencies, I tried everything from stackoverflow questions's answers and nothing helped. **What can be the root cause of these errors?**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at uni.fmi.masters.metaverse.MetaVerseApplication.main(MetaVerseApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:222) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:182) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:103) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2659) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:675) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:307) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:301) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:74) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:192) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:171) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The write format 2 is larger than the supported format 1, and the file was not opened in read-only mode [1.4.200/5]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readStoreHeader(MVStore.java:741) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:396) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:3579) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:170) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Delete the file MetaVerseDB in your user home and start again. As the exception says the file is corrupted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates the incompatible version of h2database driver with added maven. try to use newer version in order to fix the problem. as an example I updated my h2 from `1.4.187` to `2.1.212` version.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon mentioned, the problem comes from the `MetaVerseDB` file.

In case the file is not important, just delete it and start again. To find the file location, you can [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397716/where-are-my-h2-database-files)

In case your file is important, and you want to keep it to recover later, or if you want to make it fast to test, you can also rename it to `MetaVerseDB123` or something else, the new file will be created for you.